# Check if charAt are the same (case sensitive)

Tags: java, char, compare, equals, palindrome

Im have to write a method to check if a word is a palindrome. There is probably a easier way then I have it but this is just based off what I have learned so far. My method works except if there is a capital letters compared to a lowercase.

Edit: wasn't very clear. My method returns that a capital and lower case letter are the same. But I would like it to say they are different

```
public static void printPalindrome(Scanner kb) {
System.out.print("Type one or more words: ");
String s = kb.nextLine();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) {
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    char b = s.charAt(s.length()-(i+1));
    if (a==b) {
        count ++;
    } else {
        count = count;
    }
}
if (count == s.length()) {
    System.out.print(s + " is a palindrome!");
} else {
    System.out.print(s + " is not a palindrome.");
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you traversing the entire string? `i` only needs to run to the centre.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it works the way you say you want it to.. for example, "Noon" is **not** a palindrome. [See this](https://ideone.com/qqtJON) If you really do get different results, then maybe that `Scanner` is doing something it shouldn't be doing... i don't know about that though

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a slightly different approach, I'd reverse the string using [StringBuilder#reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) and then compare the two strings using [String#equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

```
String s = kb.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s).reverse();

if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(sb.toString())) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by converting the input String to upper case :

```
String s = kb.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

Or if you wish to preserve the case of the original String, create a new String and test if it's a palindrome.

```
String s = kb.nextLine();
String u = s.toUpperCase();
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < u.length();i++) {
    char a = u.charAt(i);
    char b = u.charAt(u.length()-(i+1));
    if (a==b) {
        count ++;
    } else {
        count = count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it with its ascii values

[look this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi5WT.png)

then you shoul convert your char to ascii

```
char character = 'a';
int ascii = (int) character;
```

then compare the integers

Comment: How does your answer solve uppercase-lowercase problem?